# How to concat two arrays in Nim?

Tags: arrays, concatenation, nim-lang

I'd like to concat two `array`s of the same element type to create a new `array` that contains the elements of the first array followed by the elements of the second array. Since the length is part of the type `array`, I have to calculate the length of the result `array` at compile time (`I1 + I2`). That's why I use `static[int]` as type restriction for the lengths `I1` and `I2`:

```
proc concat[I1, I2: static[int]; T](a: array[I1, T], b: array[I2, T]):
               array[I1 + I2, T] =
  for i in low(a)..high(a):
    result[i] = a[i]
  for i in low(b)..high(b):
    result[i + high(a) + 1] = b[i]

# example
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let b = [5, 6, 7]
let c = concat(a, b)

echo repr(c)
```

Unfortunately, I get this error message:

```
Error: cannot generate code for: I1
  proc concat[I1, I2: static[int]; T](a: array[I1, T], b: array[I2, T]):
                                               ^
```

Why does it not work? How do you fix it?

---

Nim Compiler Version 0.16.0 (2017-01-08) [Linux: amd64]
Copyright (c) 2006-2017 by Andreas Rumpf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me in Nim devel branch, so this is probably fixed already. You can get the devel branch or wait for the next release.

Edit: You can do your operation a bit shorter by the way:

```
proc concat[I1, I2: static[int]; T](a: array[I1, T], b: array[I2, T]): array[I1 + I2, T] =
  result[0..a.high] = a
  result[a.len..result.high] = b
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it with _Nim Compiler Version 0.16.1 (2017-05-07) [Linux: amd64]_ (current devel branch) and it works fine.